# How do you remove unity lenses?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, lenses

I installed a unity lens on 11.10 that showed the firefox bookmarks. I don't want it anymore, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove bookmarks-lens
```

Or simply search for bookmarks-lens in the ubuntu software center and click remove.