# Some lenses not working in 12.04

Tags: lenses

I have just started experimenting with extra lens in Unity. I installed some that I found listed in an AskUbuntu question.  Some of them don't seem to work.

The "Cooking" lens is supposed to show recipes, but I just get a blank result - nothing is found.

I have another lens which I assume is the youtube lens I installed, that sits and searches forever when I switch to it, and even type a search into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found was to upgrade to 12.10.  A bit drastic, I know, but they all work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Lenses available in software centre should be working OK.  All other lenses are probably private efforts and you should talk to the author if they are not working in current releases.  Because much is still changing in Unity there have been a few problems.

Here's the [cooking lens project](https://launchpad.net/lens-cooking) Launchpad page.

Here's the Launchpad [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lens-cooking/+bug/1051718) for the cooking lens problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks.  I naively thought that, as Unity and lenses had been around for a few major versions, that things would be fairly stable.  That bug report reads like a real mess.

Comment: Side question - how do you remove lenses? :)

Comment: Well, that should really be the subject of another question but it appears to have already been answered http://askubuntu.com/questions/86700/how-do-you-remove-unity-lenses . In other words, you can remove them with the reverse of the way you installed them, the same as any program.  If they are oddball ones you got from a PPA or another site, you might have to research the installation instructions that you used to find out how to remove them.

Comment: The cooking lens looked really interesting, but then I read that he had to remove a few resources for copyright reasons.  Sour grapes on the part of the website owners I think - it's just a search tool... Don't they want people to be able to find their pages?  Are they going to make Google remove links to their pages?   Bah Humbug!  Regarding the lens, it should work in 12.10 since he ported it to python, and python is OK in 12.10.  Python is _not_ OK in 12.04 but you might investigate using the older lens, with all the extra resources.